# can't add text over image dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm designing mobile webpage using HTML5+Javascript. I added a image dynamically thro' javascript. But when i tried to set a text over that image dynamically, it doesn't work.

I want the text to be appear over the image.
My code is;

```
  <script>
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  var ele = document.getElementById('container');
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  table.className = 'c1';
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  /* image added dynamically */
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "Images/car.jpeg";
  img.className = 'c3';
  var txt = document.createTextNode('IE8');

  td.appendChild(img);
  img.appendChild(txt);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
  ele.appendChild(table);
  }

  <style> .img{height:50px;width:50px;}
  .c1 {height:60px; width:100px;} 
  </style>
  <body id='container'></body>
```

I have tried by adding a div component & then adding text + background-image to it. It's also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better choice whould be to set the image as CSS `image-background` property of the text container.

```
<td style="background-image: url('path_to_image');">
```

A not so good technique would be putting the text on a container floating, with an absolute position (this whould require JS) and z-index greater than the image element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this as @Edorka suggests

td.backgroundImage="url('Images/car.jpeg')";

don't create img element.